# How to have custom expect messages with vitest?

Tags: jestjs, vitest

'Im migrating from jest to `vitest`, which has been pretty painless, except I've been using

https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-expect-message
To help give better messages to students when tests fail.

It obviously isn't written for vitest, so I don't expect it to work. Is there a vitest way to achieve the same end?

I've searched the `vitest` docs but there isn't anything that jumps out at me.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out -- the Vitest docs do not mention it anywhere, but it's built into the vitest `expect` by default. Remove the `jest-expect-message` library if using.

Then it can be the second argument in `expect`

```js
    expect(list.length, 'Make sure you have a default passenger!').toBe(1);
```